# Finding density ratios with missing information?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, planets, density

[image]

How would you go about solving this problem? You can't find the densities since the volumes are missing.

Comment: But the ratio of the two volumes is not missing. How does the volume of a shape scale with any length within it, if it is uniformly dilated?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Hint: the volume of the new planet is $(14)^3$ times the volume of the Earth.

Comment: So that means the ratio would be 1/2744. I tried that answer but it was marked wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the volume from the information given about the radius, assuming the planet to be spherical of course.

Comment: I got an answer of 3/7. What ratio did you get?